# Angular *ngIf="data$ async as data && data.payload; else noContent"

Tags: angular, templates, angular-ng-if, angular-template, angular-template-variable

I want to conditionally show a block only if it contains data, otherwise I will show a noContent block.
the data is fetched from the server.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ async as data && data.payload; else noContent">
{{data.payload | json}}
</ng-container>

<ng-template #noContent> No content found </ng-template>
```

**notes:**
1- I dont want to implement two s, i.e:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ async as data ; else noContent">
  <ng-container *ngIf="data.payload; else noContent">
  {{data.payload | json }}
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
...
```

2- the following statements are working

```
*ngIf="xx && yy"
*ngIf="data$ as data"
*ngIf="xx && data$ as data"
*ngIf="(data$ as data)?.payload?.length>0; else noContent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```js
<ng-container *ngIf="(data$ | async ) as d; else noContent">
    <ng-container *ngIf="d.payload?.length > 5 ;else noContent">
        <h3>
            {{d.payload | json}}
        </h3>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

```
<ng-template #noContent> No content found </ng-template>
```

[**StackBlitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtvpnd)

Comment: don't supress `as data`, {{data}} in your template refers to this.data in your component, try to rename data to getData inside the component and try again

Comment: I also want to check for data.payload inside the same *ngIf statement

Comment: @xxyy yoiu need to create a nested ng-container for this ,check the updated answer 